# Arc fragment showing black screen with 3-D obj model

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, arcore, sceneform

*i am share my xml and view code with screenshot. i need to load 3-D obj model *

```
class ArticleTextureActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var renderablew: ModelRenderable? = null
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_texture)
        val arFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment) as ArFragment?
        arFragment!!.setOnTapArPlaneListener { hitResult: HitResult, plane: Plane?, motionEvent: MotionEvent? ->
            val anchorNode = AnchorNode(hitResult.createAnchor())
            anchorNode.renderable = renderablew
            arFragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
        }
        buildModel()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun buildModel() {
        ModelRenderable
            .builder()
            .setSource(this, R.raw.house_obj)
            .build()
            .thenAccept { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Model built", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                renderablew = modelRenderable
            }
    }
}
```

**Here is my XML code**

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/arFragment"
            android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_350sdp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

**Here is screenshot what i am getting **

[image]

Comment: so what you want here instead of black?

Comment: i want load my 3-d object , setSource(this, R.raw.house_obj), i have pass here, but it only showing black screen.